# How to share data between ios Safari app and Native App?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

I have a need to set some data via ios Safari (a token), and then read that data (token) from a native iOS app.

i passed the context token to the app immediately via an URL-scheme by registering my app but my app Rejeced.

Comment: What do you mean by "my app Rejected"?

Comment: @ H2CO3 when my app first time open it redirect on safari after that came on my app and i got data from safari app. but apple Rejected and give reason to me "10.6 bad user experience"

Comment: The reason for the bad user experience is it sounds like you never gave your users a chance to login.  If I downloaded an app from the appstore and it redirected me straight to safari I would think that is spam.  Why can't you either open your webpage up within the app like an oauth sign in page?